# Printing nested associative array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json

I'm using this code  `$json_output = (json_decode($json, true));` to transform from JSON to an associative array in PHP.

The resulting array looks too compĺex to me, I need to print only some keys and values but they are nested and so far I haven't been able to do it, the examples I had follow for printing are too basic for this.

This is part of my JSON:

```
{
"project": {
    "company": "Company Name SA de CV",
    "name": "Project Name",
    "files": [
        {
            "project-id": "666666",
            "filenameOnDisk": "HH-ORG-CMD-GUI-File.docx",
            "uploaded-date": "2018-01-29T21:20:56Z",
            "private": "0",
            "version-id": "3939061",
            "status": "active",
            "tags": [
                {
                    "name": "OPD",
                    "id": "25047",
                    "color": "#9e6957"
                }
            ],
            "id": "3796128",
            "last-changed-on": "2018-01-29T21:21:46Z",
            "versions": [],
            "uploaded-by-user-first-name": "Someone",
            "uploaded-by-user-last-name": "Anything",
            "name": "HH-ORG-CMD-GUI-GUIA_RAPIDA_PARA_CREAR_PROCESOS",
            "size": "262747",
            "category-name": "Instructivos"
        },
        {
            "project-id": "666",
            etc...,
        },
```

When parsed looks like [image: this]

How do I print (lets say) filenameOnDisk and id keys of the Files array.

I don't know how to get to that nested array.

Comment: Why would you want to convert that good structure into a huge array? Why not work with the objects? That would be something like `$obj->project->files[0]->filenameOnDisk` then...

Comment: Read about [accessing](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.syntax.accessing) and [creating/modifying array elements using the square brackets syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.syntax.modifying).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
echo $json_output['project']['files'][0]['project-id'];
echo $json_output['project']['files'][0]['filenameOnDisk'];
echo $json_output['project']['files'][0]['version-id'];
```

Or you could put it in a foreach loop using an array of values you want (as long as they're all in the 'files' array). Eg.

```
$wantedValues = array("project-id","filenameOnDisk","version-id"); 

foreach ($wantedValues as $value) { 
  echo $json_output['project']['files'][0][$value];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I Just needed to add a couple of lines at the code provided by @SeeSamRun in order to get the full "Files" array.

```
$filesArray = $json_output['project']['files'];
$filesSize = count($filesArray);
$wantedValues = array("project-id","filenameOnDisk","version-id"); 

for ($i=0; $i < $filesSize; $i++) { 
foreach ($wantedValues as $value) {
echo $json_output['project']['files'][$i][$value];
      }
}
```